# My hyperledger sawtooth validators ran out of storage

Tags: data-management, hyperledger-sawtooth

Is there any way to move data out of the ledger while keeping the data consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Sawtooth Version 1.1 (Bumper) they've introduced "pruning" which allows you to remove generational data history through configurable settings. Check the online documentation or implementation in github to see if it addresses your needs specifically.

Clearly the integrity of the chain is a given.

Comment: You can enable pruning with the `sawtooth` CLI or a local setting:
`$ sawtooth-validator –state-pruning-block-depth 1000`
Or in config ile `/etc/sawtooth/validator.toml`: 
`state_pruning_block_depth 1000`

For more details, see PR 8 in the Sawtooth RFCs:
https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-rfcs/pull/8/files